# How can I Identify which package classes are in use in my program?

Tags: java, class

I have imported packages using `*`.

Example:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Is there a way to find out which classes of this package I am actually using in my program? I need to import only the classes I am actually using for my Java Project.

Thank you

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, CTRL+SHIFT+O should do the job. It certainly exists for other popular IDE.

Comment: Every ide has an organize imports feature, which should optimize your imports to include only what you are actually using. In eclipse the keyboard shortcut is ctrl+shift+O

Comment: You can just remove that import statement and the compiler will tell you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is good practice not to use * for imports unless you will be using each and every one. This will keep the executable from being unnecessarily large.

Like @Bill the Lizard said, the compiler will let you know which imports you forgot to add.

Comment: The class file will not include more or less content whether or not asterisk imports are used.

Answer (score 4):

Use an IDE like Eclipse to organize the imports, which will only add imports for classes that are used in the code.

The shortcut for Eclipse is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (you can even configure to run the action automatically on saving changes to a file).

For IntelliJ, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: In Eclipse, you can also set the save action to automatically organize imports.

Comment: @Compass I added that tip as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to clean up your `*` imports, the keyboard shortcuts in the other answers will do it, but if you want to be able to automatically find out what dependencies are used by some code, Oracle has created a tool called [`jdeps`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html) that comes with the JDK. It is described as:

> The `jdeps` command shows the package-level or class-level dependencies of Java class files. The input class can be a path name to a `.class` file, a directory, a JAR file, or it can be a fully qualified class name...

For example, if your classes are built to a `classes` directory, the following command would show you what classes are used by class `com.example.Foo`:

`jdeps -verbose:class -cp classes com.example.Foo`

See the [`jdeps` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html) for details on usage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reflection (getPackage() or getClassName()) for the package details.

try {

```
    System.out.println(Class.class.forName("java.lang.Integer").getPackage());
 }
 catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
 }
```